# Get label instead of API name in salesforce formula

Tags: formula, formula-field, image-formula

I am trying to add image plus text value to a field in the case object. In the below formula I am adding an icon based on the Type picklist value chosen and also at the end appending the label of the picklist item chosen instead of the API name.

```
IMAGE(CASE( Type,
'Billing', '/resource/CaseIcons/Billing.svg',
'Service', '/resource/CaseIcons/Service.svg',
'Technical', '/resource/CaseIcons/Technical.svg',
'Retention', '/resource/CaseIcons/Retention.svg',
'Account Action', '/resource/CaseIcons/AccountActions.svg',
'/s.gif'), "Issue Type") + " " +  (CASE(Type,
"Billing","Billing",
"Service", "Service Change",
"Technical","Technical",
"Retention","Retention",
"Account Action","Account Action"
))
```

I am getting this error when check the syntax -
**`Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected 10, received 11`**

The final result I am looking for is image plus the label of the picklist item selected like in the image attached.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing a default case on your second case statement

```
IMAGE(CASE( Type,
'Billing', '/resource/CaseIcons/Billing.svg',
'Service', '/resource/CaseIcons/Service.svg',
'Technical', '/resource/CaseIcons/Technical.svg',
'Retention', '/resource/CaseIcons/Retention.svg',
'Account Action', '/resource/CaseIcons/AccountActions.svg',
'/s.gif'), "Issue Type") + " " +  (CASE(Type,
"Billing","Billing",
"Service", "Service Change",
"Technical","Technical",
"Retention","Retention",
"Account Action","Account Action",
"ErrorError"
))
```

Comment: Awesome Kayden, I have been stuck with this for a while.